# Is it possible to have a required field validator for Taxonomy webtagging control

Tags: taxonomy

Is it possible to have a required field validator for Taxonomy webtagging control. I tried using standard Required field validator but it fails. Is there any property in taxonomy webtagging control.??

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = $("#<%=TaxonamyControlID.ClientID %>").find("input[type='hidden']").val()

if(value == '') 
{ 
    alert('please enter a value') ; return false; 
} 
else 
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Required Field Validator that comes out of the box will not work with Taxonomy web tagging control because the tagging control which appears like a text box (input type=text) is NOT an input control when it renders in browser.

You can use CustomValidator though as shown in article below:

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

At server side you can check Text Property of control and if its empty, set e.IsValid = false.

Answer (score 0):

Actual value of the taxonomy input field is stored in a hidden input field.

If Javascript is OK for you, and you can surround your taxonomy control with DIV ID *myTaxDiv*, you can get the value quite easily. I've used this jQuery command:

> j("#myTaxDiv > span > span > input[type='hidden']").val("");

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully validate a TaxonomyWebTaggingControl using a CustomValidator as shown below.  In my case the taxonomy field is not required but I wanted to make sure the user entered a valid value.  In your case you could update the event handler to check if the user entered a value and set the ErrorMessage appropriately.

Be sure NOT to set the ControlToValidate property of the CustomValidator or you will get an error.

In your ASPX page

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ID="region" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl><br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="regionValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="regionValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

In your code behind

```
protected void regionValidator_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
        string reason;
        if (!region.Validate(out reason))
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            regionValidator.ErrorMessage = reason;
        }
    }
```