# How to make taxonomy picker required when used in visual web part?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, visual-web-part, taxonomy, validation

I have created a visual web part in which user has to specify a field's value from taxonomy picker control. I want to make that value mandatory. The control is placed successfully but when I use the `<asp:requieredfieldvalidator>` it throws error.

My code is:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl runat="server" 
        ID="taxProjectOwnerDepartment" Visible="true" IsMulti="false" IsDisplayPickerButton="true">
            </Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProjectOwnerDepartment" runat="server" ControlToValidate="taxProjectOwnerDepartment"
             ErrorMessage="Please Specfiy Owner's Department" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" />
```

The log shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0bR6.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code to:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl runat="server" ID="taxProjectOwnerDepartment" Visible="true" IsMulti="false" IsDisplayPickerButton="true">
</Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="rfvProjectOwnerDepartment" runat="server"  OnServerValidate="validator_ServerValidate" />
```

now in your codebehind add the new method `validator_ServerValidate`:

```
    protected void validator_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string errorMessage = "Please Specfiy Owner's Department";
        if (!taxProjectOwnerDepartment.Validate(out errorMessage))
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
            rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

the value of taxonomy is stored in a hidden input field so its not really a input field and throws an error when calling `ControlToValidate="taxProjectOwnerDepartment"` unfortunatly

[Is it possible to have a required field validator for Taxonomy webtagging control](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28602/is-it-possible-to-have-a-required-field-validator-for-taxonomy-webtagging-contro)

**EDIT**

For issues with empty input you need to add:

```
if(e.Value.Length == 8)
{
    e.IsValid = true;
}
else
{
    e.IsValid = false;
}
```

so code will look like this:

```
    protected void validator_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string errorMessage = "Please Specfiy Owner's Department";

        if(e.Value.Length == 0)
        {
             args.IsValid = false;
             rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
             rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
             rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!taxProjectOwnerDepartment.Validate(out errorMessage))
            {
               args.IsValid = false;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

so now we have changed the codebehind to first check if the length is correct (not 0) if its isnt 0 then do check what was entered to validate! code is a bit bulky, you could change it so that the if function is in one checking with an or statment like this:

```
    protected void validator_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string errorMessage = "Please Specfiy Owner's Department";

            if (e.Value.Length == 0 || !taxProjectOwnerDepartment.Validate(out errorMessage))
            {
               args.IsValid = false;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
               rfvProjectOwnerDepartment.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I am not finding `region.Validate`

Comment: sorry just updated the code! just copy paste the code and it will work, iv changed everything so that it matches

Comment: tried as per your suggestion but not working

Comment: what happens? does it show an error message or simply does nothing atall? make sure you try the new code that iv just ammened! this code should work!

Comment: if that doesnt work you can try this method! its very similar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.aspx use the same code that i posted but also add in from the link above from the onload function

Comment: I made the changes as per your new answer but it does not alert that field is required if I put it empty.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/UZPdBqUm), is the C# code and [here](http://pastebin.com/j4tH7GCL) is ascx code.

Comment: @users1100 just ammended my answer! this will solve the empty textbox issue for you ;) , sorry cant see code unfortunatly due to company restricions on sites arhh, but the solution should work perfectly for you!

Comment: I made the changes and added a code after running the code, I got this error. `Control 'taxProjectOwnerDepartment' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'rfvProjectOwnerDepartment' cannot be validated` from error log

Comment: sorry me being stupid! just ammended the code! its just an extra validation checking if e(event args) is greater than 0

Comment: no probs happy to help!