# Unable to validate sharepoint date time control

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, validation, datetimecontrol

I have added a `<SharePoint:DateTimeControl>` in my visual web part and I want to make it mandatory. To do so I referred [this](http://sharepointdata.blogspot.in/2009/06/sharepoint-datetime-control-validation.html) link and used as per my code.

My code is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" Text="Planned End Date"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
            <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" DateOnly="true"/>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID ="rfvProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Specfiy Project Planned End Date"
             ControlToValidate="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting error i.e. `=Unable to find control id 'dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'rfvProjectPlannedEndDate'.`

What should I do?

Comment: Tried as per your suggestion and its giving this error:`=Unable to find control id 'dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'rfvProjectPlannedEndDate'.`

Comment: Now error occurs: `Error=Control 'dtcProjectPlannedEndDate' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'rfvProjectPlannedEndDate' cannot be validated`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code is fine appart from one part, you looping on the validation! you need to set date type at the end:

so you have:

```
ControlToValidate="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate"
```

should be:

```
ControlToValidate="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDateDate"
```

i got that from the error you shown:

> Unable to find control id
>   'dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate' referenced by the
>   'ControlToValidate' property of 'rfvProjectPlannedEndDate'.

so it got the first part correct but its after $ that it fails.

reading the error: its failing at `ControlToValidate` and more specifically `dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDate` , `tcProjectPlannedEndDate` is correct as that is the correct field name, `$` means to validate against `tcProjectPlannedEndDate` but missing the data type which in your case is (`date`) type!

full working code is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" Text="Planned End Date"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
            <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" DateOnly="true"/>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID ="rfvProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Specfiy Project Planned End Date"
             ControlToValidate="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDateDate" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

more info on control to validation and how it should look:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator

what i mean is your asking to validate a field name by a field name but missed the type which is date ;) in sudo it would look like

```
if ((field name == field name) = date(type) )
{
  //show nothing
}
else
{
  //show error 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it worked perfectly. But I did not get where I was wrong? Will you please specify?

Comment: what i mean is your asking to validate a field name by a field name but missed the type which is date ;) in sudo it would look like (field name == field name) = date(type)

Comment: Thank you sir for explainig.. Sir, I am still working for [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78561/how-to-make-taxonomy-picker-required-when-used-in-visual-web-part) query. Did you get any idea?

Comment: im at work atm and cant view anything from pastbin or any images posted via image hosting sites :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this way!!!!!!!!

```
    <sharepoint:datetimecontrol id="txtPrepDate" runat="server" dateonly="true">

         <asp:comparevalidator id="CompareValidator2" runat="server" forecolor="Red" controltovalidate="txtPrepDate$txtPrepDateDate" type="Date" operator="DataTypeCheck" errormessage="Please enter an valid date" display="Dynamic"></asp:comparevalidator>

    </sharepoint:datetimecontrol>
```

NOTE : Here ControlToValidate property you need to set as {DateControlID}${DateControlID}Date then only it will work otherwise it will through error

Also note operator = "DataTypeCheck"

http://kancharla-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/sharepoint-datetimecontrol-validation.html

Comment: although this is a good answer please dont just copy off the net and not reference where you get it from!

Answer (score 0):

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" DateOnly="true" IsRequiredField="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID ="rfvProjectPlannedEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Specfiy Project Planned End Date"
         ControlToValidate="dtcProjectPlannedEndDate$dtcProjectPlannedEndDateDate" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Try the above!

Also, check there should be a property named `IsRequiredField` in SharePoint:DateTimeControl, make it true..

Comment: I tried the same way but not working. Throwing same error.